# how to display the image on toplevel window having name I

Tags: python, tkinter

I tried to get the image on toplevel window but the code gets an error.

```
    canvas.creat_image(0,0,visual=I_tt,anchor=NW)
    AttributeError: 'Canvas' object has no attribute 'creat_image'



canvas=Canvas(I, width=750, height=500)
canvas.pack(expand=YES, fill=BOTH)
I_tt=PhotoImage(file="F:\\2nd Sem\\python\\course project\\I.png")
canvas.creat_image(0,0,visual=I_tt,anchor=NW)
```

Comment: Just as a guess: have you tried using `create_image`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You spelt create wrong.

change

```
canvas.creat_image(0,0,visual=I_tt,anchor=NW)
```

to

```
canvas.create_image(0,0,visual=I_tt,anchor=NW)
```